# webview overlaps appbar in Xamarin Android app

Tags: webview, xamarin.android

i am using xamarin android app template with drawerlayout.i am using webview in app_bar_main.axml. when the activity is launched .it overlaps the appbar and does not show toolbar.my app_bar_main.axml is as follows: i want to show webview but below appbar.the webview is below toolbar but contents of toolbar are hidden.i want contents of toolbar so that i can navigate through toolbar in appbar .app_bar_main.axml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/StoreView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> 

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the MainActivity.cs code is here.
the app_bar_main.axml is in activity_main.axml  as produced by drawerlayout template.

````
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
            fab.Click += FabOnClick;

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            // start store activity
            if (IsOnline() == true)
            {
                message = "items";
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(StoreActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("Data", "message");
                StartActivity(intent);
            }

        }
      ```
````

Comment: Could you share some pictures to show what you are trying to do? Also please share the code of the web view page and the code of the page that calls the web view page. I have a feeling that you are missing some attributes

Comment: dear i have simple xamarin android app with drawerlayout navigation template in which we can show webview but it should be below toolbar. in my app when new activity (which has webview) is launched it overlaps everthing on screen.i want the toolbar to show above webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo which achieve your function.The main code is as follows:
The `activity_main.axml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#33B86C"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
  {
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    private string mDrawerTitle;
    private string[] mContentTitles;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        mDrawerTitle = this.Title;
        mContentTitles= this.Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.contents_array);

        toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu);
        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null)
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
        drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.SyncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) //first launch
        {
            toolbar.Title = mContentTitles[0];
            var fragment = WebviewFragment.NewInstance(0);

            var fragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
            var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.Commit();
        }
    }

    void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) => {

            int ItemId = e.MenuItem.ItemId;

            e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);

            int index = 0;
            if (ItemId == Resource.Id.nav_home) {
                index = 0;
            } else if (ItemId == Resource.Id.nav_messages) {
                index = 1;
            }
            else if (ItemId == Resource.Id.nav_about)
            {
                index = 2;
            }

            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            var fragment = WebviewFragment.NewInstance(index);

            var fragmentManager = this.FragmentManager;
            var ft = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.Commit();

            // update selected item title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerTitle = mContentTitles[index];


            drawer.CloseDrawers();
        };
    }    

    internal class WebviewFragment : Fragment
    {
        public const string ARG_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public WebviewFragment()
        {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        public static Fragment NewInstance(int position)
        {
            Fragment fragment = new WebviewFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.PutInt(WebviewFragment.ARG_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.Arguments = args;
            return fragment;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                           Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_content2, container, false);
            var i = this.Arguments.GetInt(ARG_NUMBER);
            var url = this.Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.weburls_array)[i];

            var title = this.Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.contents_array)[i];

            var web_view = rootView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            web_view.LoadUrl(url);


            this.Activity.Title = title;
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    internal class MyActionBarDrawerToggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle
    {
        MainActivity owner;

        public MyActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity activity, DrawerLayout layout, Toolbar toolbar, int openRes, int closeRes)
            : base(activity, layout, toolbar, openRes, closeRes)
        {
            owner = activity;
        }

        public override void OnDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
        {
            owner.toolbar.Title = owner.Title;
            owner.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public override void OnDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            owner.toolbar.Title = owner.mDrawerTitle;
            owner.InvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

strings.xml

```
  <resources>
  <string name="app_name">DrawLayoutApp</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
  <string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
  <string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

  <string-array name="contents_array">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Messages</item>
    <item>About</item>
 </string-array>
 <string-array name="weburls_array">
   <item>https://www.google.com/</item>
   <item>https://msdn.itellyou.cn/</item>
   <item>https://www.baidu.com/</item>
 </string-array>
</resources>
```

menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:title="Home" />
 <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
    android:title="Messages" />
 <item
    android:id="@+id/nav_about"
    android:title="About" />
</group>
</menu>
```

The effect is as follows:
[image]

Comment: very thanks dear @Jessie Zhang , i am still learner (newbee)so please i will be thankful if you comment all parts of MainActivity.cs so that i can understand and put my logic their.regards.

Comment: @FiazAhmed   Here is a full code of this demo, you can check it : https://github.com/jessiezh0320/DrawerLayoutDemo